# Timer stops working after app resume (Android)

Tags: java, android, timer, libgdx, onresume

I'm using three timer to trigger different periodic tasks (not all enabled at the same time).  However after pausing/resuming the app (by switching to a different app), some of the timers stop working. After reading through the web I found that there was a bug in libGDX related to this, but it has already been fixed. Awkwardly enough, only two of the timers stop working while the third one works fine.

```
@Override
public void create ( ) {
    createTimers();
    easterTimer.start();
    inputTimer.stop();
    refreshTimer.start();

    //More stuff...
}


//Called by "onRestart()", on other class, after calling super.onRestart method
public void restart(){
    createTimers();
    simulationStatus = simulationStatus_stop;
    selectedOption = -1;
    draggingFinger = false;
    refreshTimer.stop();
    easterTimer.start();
    inputTimer.start();



}


private void createTimers() {
    easterTimer = new Timer();
    easterTimer.scheduleTask(new Timer.Task() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("easter");
            //Do stuff....
        }
    }, 0, 0.25f);


    inputTimer = new Timer();
    inputTimer.scheduleTask(new Timer.Task() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("input");
            //Do stuff....
        }
    }, 0, 0.01f);


    refreshTimer = new Timer();
    refreshTimer.scheduleTask(new Timer.Task() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("refresh");
            //Do stuff....
        }
    }, 0, (float) 1 / 80);
}
```

Please note that in the following situation the "refreshTimer" is disabled, so it should not be printing anything -- as it's doing. Though I have tested and this Timer is the only one that works properly after resume.

```
08-07 23:52:52.450    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/System.out﹕ input
08-07 23:52:52.450    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/System.out﹕ input
08-07 23:52:52.450    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/System.out﹕ input
08-07 23:52:52.490    8762-8762/com.asjv.echarges.android I/AndroidInput﹕ sensor listener tear down
08-07 23:52:52.490    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ paused
08-07 23:52:58.430    8762-8762/com.asjv.echarges.android I/AndroidInput﹕ sensor listener setup
08-07 23:52:58.490    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ resumed
08-07 23:52:58.490    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/System.out﹕ input
08-07 23:52:58.500    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/System.out﹕ easter
08-07 23:52:58.500    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/System.out﹕ input
08-07 23:52:58.500    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/System.out﹕ input
08-07 23:52:58.500    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/System.out﹕ input
08-07 23:52:58.500    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/System.out﹕ easter
08-07 23:52:58.500    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/System.out﹕ input
08-07 23:52:58.500    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/System.out﹕ input
08-07 23:52:58.500    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/System.out﹕ input
08-07 23:52:58.500    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/System.out﹕ input
08-07 23:52:58.500    8762-8805/com.asjv.echarges.android I/System.out﹕ input
08-07 23:52:59.140    8762-8762/com.asjv.echarges.android I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41cbafa0 time:92087596
```

The bottom line is: does anyone more knowledgeable than me have any hint on why this may be happening? Or even what may be triggering the log "Activity_idle id:", since its after that that the timers seem to stop working?

For reference, I'm developing for Android and using libGDX 1.6.4

Comment: Have you tried just putting the code in the 'onResume' method instead of 'onRestart'?

Comment: I have not.  I will try it when I get back home. Could it be that I need to use runOnUIThread(...)?

Comment: hmmmmm... this comment is to make me keep track of the question

Comment: @M0CH1R0N The strangest thing just happened. In the beginning I was using libGDX 1.5.X, and when this was not working, so I overrode the onRestart method in an attempt to fix the problem. When this didn't work I went around the web and found the reference to bug in libGDX that had been fixed, so I updated the version I was using to 1.6.4, just in case I had a buggy version. Still didn't work. Tried all I could think of to make it work, including your suggestions, to no success. Then, by chance, I commented out, from the override, all the code except the super.onRestart. It works now...

Comment: Ahh, the mysteries of programming!