# Android App doesn't continue after splash screen

Tags: android, android-activity

Good day

I recently encountered the problem where my app doesn't continue to the Main Activity after the Splash Screen. It goes to the Main Activity the first time it is installed but after that it doesn't anymore.

I have looked at both of these posts:
[token=android.os.BinderProxy error android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174121/token-android-os-binderproxy-error-android)
[Timer stops working after app resume (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887882/timer-stops-working-after-app-resume-android)

Neither of them fully answer the guestion and are different from my example.

Essentially the person needs to accept the EULA before they can get to the Main Activity. If they exit out of the App without accepting the EULA, it diverts them to it when they go in again.

Here is the Activity Code:

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

boolean a;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);


    final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    final boolean firstRun = settings.getBoolean("firstRun", false);
    final SharedPreferences disc = getSharedPreferences("disc", 0);
    final boolean disclaimer = disc.getBoolean("disclaimer", false);


    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                sleep(1500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {


                if (!firstRun) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("firstRun", true);
                    editor.apply();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, Instruction.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();


                } else {
                    try {
                        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                        a = bundle.getBoolean("key");

                        if (a == true) {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = disc.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean("disclaimer", true);
                            editor.apply();

                            Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, siteCheck.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        if (disclaimer == true) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, siteCheck.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        } else {
                            Intent d = new Intent(Splash.this, Instruction.class);
                            startActivity(d);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }


    };
    thread.start();


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

The LogCat is as follows:

```
10-09 12:26:36.820 10246-10246/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@279459f time:16608813
```

This is the message it ends on. It doesn't continue from there but rather just stays on the Splash Screen.

Could it possibly have anything to do with my use of the Thread? If then, why only now and not earlier in development.

I would really appreciate any help, guidance or advice.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: it is probably the firstRun and key is false. *Could it possibly have anything to do with my use of the Thread*, No it is not

Comment: Ok, great. I'll quickly have a look into it. Thank you so much.

Comment: its all the logcat prints ? nothing more ?

Comment: It turns out that the issue is in fact with my shared preferences. Now I just need to figure out exactly what is causing. I'll post the results for anyone else with the problem.

Comment: @Amir Ziarati it doe print other things but they have nothing to do with the issue (things like Ad Requests). I used Log statements to 'Debug' or see what the app was doing. When running the second time, it runs the try statement but then gets stuck there. So I need to figure out why now.

Comment: use the method i wrote in answer instead of thread.sleep() its cleaner and better and  debugging errors will be easier.

Comment: Great, I will definitely use it now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

use code below for starting your activity from splashScreen: note that finish(); also should be called

```
 Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    h.postDelayed(() -> {
       if (!firstRun) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("firstRun", true);
                editor.apply();
                Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, Instruction.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            } else {
                try {
                    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                    a = bundle.getBoolean("key");

                    if (a == true) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = disc.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("disclaimer", true);
                        editor.apply();

                        Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, siteCheck.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    if (disclaimer == true) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, siteCheck.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else {
                        Intent d = new Intent(Splash.this, Instruction.class);
                        startActivity(d);
                    }

                }
            }
    }, 1500);
```

Comment: you sure you dont wanna finish splash Activity in case you start `siteCheck` activity ?

Comment: Thank you so much for the code Amir Ziariti. I will look into it now. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use thread like this. You can use a handler for it.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (!firstRun) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("firstRun", true);
                    editor.apply();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, Instruction.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();


                } else {
                    try {
                        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                        a = bundle.getBoolean("key");

                        if (a == true) {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = disc.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean("disclaimer", true);
                            editor.apply();

                            Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, siteCheck.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        if (disclaimer == true) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, siteCheck.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        } else {
                            Intent d = new Intent(Splash.this, Instruction.class);
                            startActivity(d);
                        }

                    }
                }
                finish();
            }
        }, 1500);
    }
```